# Is it valid HTML5 to use a single tag for a div?

Tags: html, xhtml

For example: `<div/>` instead of `<div></div>`.
I did this and apparently the HTML5 validator passed this as valid. I was wondering it this is actually true?

PS: I'm serving page as application/xhtml+xml

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is *not* valid HTML 5 (HTML does not allow shorttags, the equivalent HTML construct is a single opening `div` tag). It is valid XHTML 5, as it is valid XML.

The reason why you might see this pass through a validator just fine is because of what you stated:

> PS: I'm serving page as application/xhtml+xml

Which means that you tell the validator that it must treat your markup as XML. In other words your page is *not* HTML 5 at all.

Comment: +1. By default, no elements support the self-closing syntax. Elements which have no content model / empty content model *can* be self-closed for XHTML compliance, but the browser treats them the same either way. For example, `<img />` and `<img>` are the same.

Comment: In cases like this, please try to distinguish between HTML5 the spec, and the HTML (text/html) and XHTML (application/xhtml+xml) serializations contained within. Although this answer is essentially correct until the last sentence, the XHTML page is indeed HTML5.

Answer (score 17):

That syntax is allowed for a [specific subset of HTML5 elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#start-tags), known as [`void` elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#void-elements), and a few other cases:

> Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/). This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.

Void elements:

> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

They're not allowed for any others, including `<div>`.

(I'd originally answered that yes, this is valid HTML5, since it's such a common construct in XML. Rex M, and a close reading of the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#start-tags), tells me that I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

No, technically using a self-closing `<div/>` tag is invalid HTML5. Using `<div></div>` works fine.