# HTML 5 with PHP XSL transformer

Tags: php, xml, html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to generate valid HTML 5 output using XSL transformer in PHP and I am having difficulty doing so. Here is the sample PHP code:

```
<?php
$xml_source = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><content/>';
$xsl_source = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
   <xsl:template match="content">
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&#10;</xsl:text>
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
           <body>
           <div style="color: green"></div>
           This text should be black
           <br/>
           This black text is on next line
           </body>                      
       </html>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOD;

$xml = new DomDocument;
$xml->LoadXML($xml_source);

$xsl = new DomDocument;
$xsl->loadXML($xsl_source);

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor;
$xslt->importStyleSheet( $xsl );
echo $xslt->transformToXML( $xml );
```

When `<xsl:output method="html"` it generates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <body>
        <div style="color: green"></div>
        This text should be black
        <br></br>
        This black text is on next line
    </body>
</html>
```

`<br></br>` gets interpreted into TWO breaks

When `<xsl:output method="xml"` it generates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <body>
        <div style="color: green" />
        This text should be black
        <br />
        This black text is on next line
    </body>
</html>
```

The `<div />` is self closing and that gets interpreted as just an opening `<div>` and the text is green.

I need your advice on how to proceed. Is there some undocumented option in PHP XSL processor to make only some tags self-closing. Is there an alternative to built in XSLT processor?

Comment: A possible work around to this is to keep output as 'xml' and to add `&#160;` or `<xsl:comment/>` in empty tags that suppose to have closing tag. like so `<div style="color: green" ><xsl:comment/></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Since XHTML output is not available in XSLT 1.0 do following:

First, keep `xsl:output` as `xml`.

Second, force certain tags to render with separate closing tag by inserting something in the middle. For example, add `&#160;` or `<xsl:comment/>` in empty tags that suppose to have closing tag. like so `<div style="color: green" ><xsl:comment/></div>` or `<script src="http://asdfasdf">&#160;</script>`. If you are converting XHTML source in XSL then do similar thing, but of course use `<!---->` instead of `xsl:comment`

Third, make sure not to remove empty comments and spaces from tags with your XSL templates. In all my stylesheets I include something like this.

```
    <xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

This has worked very well for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML does not have self-closing tags.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852469/is-it-valid-html5-to-use-a-single-tag-for-a-div) Primarily because HTML is not XML.

`<br></br>` gets interpretted as 2 breaks, as a `<br>` tag has no closing tag, which is why it tries to render it as two breaks.

If you can render it as [XHTML with the correct DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), or try another approach.

Comment: Yep. Thats pretty much what the question is about.