# AngularJS bug in ng-include when not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

See plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/O3NSb2VEwAEDrkmtoKZ6?p=preview (version 15).

I have a simple example using **ng-include** to render a hierarchical template. It worls correctly if jQuery is included. Otherwise: it only renders the text of the chapter. If the rendering of the chapter text is commented out it correctly renders the text of the paragraphs. It looks like a bug in the AngularJS JQLite implementation, I think in the "after" function with implementation:

```
after: function(element, newElement) {
   var index = element, parent = element.parentNode;
   forEach(new JQLite(newElement), function(node){
      parent.insertBefore(node, index.nextSibling);
      index = node;
   });
}
```

Because I get the error: **TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null**.

My code as can be found in the above mentioned plunker is as follows:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS template issue</title>
  <!-- uncomment line below to get it workinG using jQuery -->
  <!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-include="'template.html'"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

var lorumIpsumText = "<p>Lorem ipsum:<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul></p>";

var chaptercontent = { 
  "Id":"SampleId1","Title":"1. Sample chapter one","Content":"<p>Text of sample chapter one<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul></p>",
      "Paragraphs":[
          {"Id":"SampleId1.1", "Title":"1.1 First sample paragraph", "Content":lorumIpsumText, "Paragraphs":[]},
          {"Id":"SampleId1.2", "Title":"1.2 Second sample paragraph", "Content":lorumIpsumText, "Paragraphs":[]},
      ]
};

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trustAsHtml = function(html) { return $sce.trustAsHtml(html); };
  $scope.chaptercontent = chaptercontent;
});
```

**template.html:**

```
<script id="paragraphTmpl.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <h4>{{paragraph.Title}}</h4>
    <!-- comment line below to have the paragraphs render correctly --> 
    <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(paragraph.Content)"/>
    <ng-include ng-repeat="paragraph in paragraph.Paragraphs" 
                src="'paragraphTmpl.html'">
</script>

<div>
    <h3>{{chaptercontent.Title}}</h3>

    <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(chaptercontent.Content)"/>
    <ng-include ng-repeat="paragraph in chaptercontent.Paragraphs" 
                src="'paragraphTmpl.html'"/>
</div>
```

Any advise on getting this to work **without** jQuery is much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to Ilan the issue is solved by not using a self-closing `<div ng-bind-html='...'/>`, but by writing it as `<div ng-bind-html='...'></div>`. I don't understand why, but jQuery seems to solve this case. See http://plnkr.co/edit/O3NSb2VEwAEDrkmtoKZ6?p=preview version 17 for the correct results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### After a short debugging, I found the bug is with your template:

You forget to close this div with `</div>`:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(paragraph.Content)"></div>
```

This mistake makes `element.parentNode` to be `null`:

```
after: function(element, newElement) {
   var index = element, parent = element.parentNode; // null
```

The implementation of jQuery is a little different but that's not a bug with jqLite.

---

#### self-closing div tags ( `<div/>` ) ?

**HTML 5** doesn't support self-closing div tags.

Check this question: [Is it valid HTML5 to use a single tag for a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852469/is-it-valid-html5-to-use-a-single-tag-for-a-div)

**XHTML** ( which I definitely don't care about ) supports self-closing tags for all elements.

See  [What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj)

Your code is not compliant with XHTML anyway.

Comment: Hi Ilan, great you found the issue. But the crazy thing is that if the tag is self-closing as in  `<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(paragraph.Content)"/>` it dies NOT work, but when it is written as  `<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(paragraph.Content)"></div>` it works....

Comment: Self closing div in html5 means <div>, not <div></div>: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: @Paddy This is a self closing tag: `<div />` , have you even read the answer?

Comment: @Illan Frumer - your edit wasn't present when i commented.  Was intended as a response to the OP anyway.

Comment: @Ilan: thanks for enhancing your initial answer. Never knew that self-closing tags are not supported in Html5. Still strange that jQuery is smart enough to "solve" these kind of "errors"... maybe it is too smart.

Comment: Self-closing tags are also an issue in AngularJS. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25012451/476786