# Text between directive tags

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have a directive named `my-directive`.

How do I access or manipulate the text between the directive tags in the directive code, like this:

`<my-directive> Custom Text <my-directive>`

And my directive code:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        ...
        template: '<div>...Custom Text somewhere inside div... </div>'
    };
);
```

Comment: do you want to manipulate it inside directive or outside?

Comment: I'm doing it inside. I've edited the question. I'll appreciate if you can show me both examples, inside and outside the directive. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that you are using a template changes everything. The template will replace the inner content. What are you hoping to do with the context before it is replaced? Are you just wanting to move the content to someplace inside the template? Do you need to change the content at all?

Comment: Yes, I just need to move the content somewhere in the template `<div>`. By the way, this just came by curiosity, if it's possible to put texts between directive (esp. element type) and place it wherever you want in the template, and if it's easier than using (scope) attributes esp. for static texts.

Comment: You are basically describing what ng-transclude is used for. However ng-transclude can more more than just text and all angular element will be compiled and bound correctly. See my answer below for how to use ng-transclude

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`ng-transclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) directive in your template.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>
    }
});
```

Moves the previous inner content to where the ng-transclude is in the template.

[Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MVPRHZxmzsX5KuiNgvkq?p=preview)

Comment: I think [divs need to be properly closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852469/is-it-valid-html5-to-use-a-single-tag-for-a-div).

Comment: Possibly. I am on a tablet and got lazy.

Comment: By the way, aside from static texts, would it work on `<my-directive>{{some angular expression}}<my-directive>`?

Comment: Absolutely. You could even have nested directives get moved.

Comment: Template string is not terminated.

Answer (score 0):

if you give template in your directive. it will replace the text inside the html

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(elem) {
      elem.replaceWith(markdown.toHTML(elem.html()));
    }
  }
});
```